# Mongoose number of documents referenced in a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collections

User:

```
email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
team: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'team', required: true},
```

And Team:

```
 name: { type: String, required: true },
 active: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: true},
```

I want to get all the teams and the number of users in that team, How would I approch this using Mongoose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Teams` model and perform an aggregate query.

First we join all users from the `users` collection. Then we create an extra field called `user_amount` in which we store the size of the `users` array. In the last step we remove the `users` property but if you need this array just remove the last step of this pipeline.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mT99q-Smlhz)

```
Teams.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "team",
      "as": "users"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "user_amount": {
        "$size": "$users"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "users"
  }
])
```